# How can I keep an iterator's type generic?

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I am having some trouble with an instance variable of a template class. My goal is to store a list of pairs of an integer and an iterator. The iterator is from a list of class B objects. My problem the compiler wants me to declare the type of class B, but for my application, I would like to keep it generic at this point. Is this possible?

```
template <typename T>
class A {
  public:
    A() {}
    std::pair<int, std::list<B<T>>::iterator> foo; /* Does not compile. See error 1. */
    std::list<B<T>>::iterator bar; /* Does not compile. See error 2. */

    std::pair<int, std::list<B<int>>::iterator> foo; /* Compiles just fine. */
    std::list<B<int>>::iterator bar; /* Compiles just fine. */
```

ERROR 1:  type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template struct std::pair’
             std::list>::iterator>

note:   expected a type, got ‘std::__cxx11::list >::iterator’

ERROR 2: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::__cxx11::list >::iterator’ because ‘std::__cxx11::list >’ is a dependent scope
   std::list>::iterator bar;

Comment: `typename` is the _"magic"_ word ...

Comment: _"Would you perhaps link me to the duplicate?"_ Press F5 and follow the link appearing at the top of your question.

Comment: @user0042 Thank you! I really thought the compiler was telling me to put another type name, not to clarify that I wanted a typename.